# Prime ideal lies above

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm reading the book *Algebra* by Lang. In the page 338, it is written that:

Let $A$ be a subring of $B$. Let $p$ be a prime ideal of $A$ and let $P$ be a prime ideal of $B$. We say that $P$ **lies above** $p$ if $P\cap A=p$.

1. I cannot understand this sentence: If that is the case, then the injection $A\rightarrow B$ induces an injection of the factor ring:

$$A/p \rightarrow B/P$$

2. Also, if $B$ is integral over $A$, then $B/P$ is integral over $A/p$.

For question 1, I us the map $$\tilde{\phi}:A/p \rightarrow B/P$$ by $\tilde{\phi}(a+p)=\phi(a)+P$ where $\phi$ is the injection $A \rightarrow B$. Then I want to show that if $\phi(a_1)-\phi(a_2)\in P$ then $a_1-a_2\in p$. However $\phi$ is not homomorphism, even for the homomorphism case I couldn't show the injectivity.

For question 2, it refers to prop 1.5 of the book which says that if B be integral over A and $\sigma$ be homomorphism then $\sigma(B)$ is integral over $\sigma(A)$. It's not obvious for me how I can use this lemma.

Comment: Why do you believe that $\phi$ is not a homomorphism? It’s the *subring* embedding, so it *must* be a homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the composition of maps $A\hookrightarrow B \to B/P$. This is a homomorphism, since it is a composition of homomorphisms. What is the kernel of this ring homomorphism?

Well, it consists precisely of $A\cap P$. But this is $\mathfrak{p}$. Therefore, by the Fundamental Theorem of Homomorphisms, this composition induces an injection $A/\mathfrak{p}\to B/P$.

What is the definition of this embedding? Precisely the one you give! So why are you asserting that $\phi(a+\mathfrak{p}) = \phi(a)+P$ is *not* a homomorphism?

Note that all the work is done by the First Isomorphism Theorem.

As for the second question, if $B$ is integral over $A$, then $\pi(B)$ is integral over $\pi(A)$, where $\pi\colon B\to B/P$ is the canonical projection. But $\pi(B)=B/P$, and $\pi(A) = AP/P\cong A/(A\cap P) = A/\mathfrak{p}$. That is, $B/P$ is integral over $A/\mathfrak{p}$ (identified as a subring of $B/P$ via the embedding given above).

Comment: The kernel of the above map shouldn't be $\phi^{-1}(S)$?, which is not necessarily equal to $A\cap S$ unless you assume that $\phi$ is identity map.

Comment: @S_Alex: First, $A$ is a **subring**, so it is a subset and your $\phi$ **should** be the inclusion map (that is, the identity of $B$ restricted to $A$). Second, even if it wasn’t, **by definition** you are assuming that $S\cap \phi(A) = \phi(\mathfrak{p})$, so $\phi^{-1}(S) =\mathfrak{p}$ does in fact hold, because $\phi$ is **by definition** one-to-one: it is an *inclusion* map!

Comment: @S_alex: I mean, the entire definition assumes that $A\subseteq B$; otherwise, how are you even writing down “$S\cap A= \mathfrak{p}$” in the first place?

Comment: If in the first place it was stated that the map $A\rightarrow B$ is an inclusion map, then I would agree with you. But if $A\subset B$ and $\phi: A\rightarrow 
 B$ be an injection, then $\phi$ is not necessarily an inclusion map. For instance, let $B=Z$ and $A=2Z$ then the map $\phi(2n)=2n+1$ is an injection but not identity.

Comment: @S_Alex: It is stated that $A$ is a **subring**; that means that $A\subseteq B$; the “injection” mentioned **is** the inclusion map, and a homomorphism. You are misunderstanding the statement. In the context given, “the injection” (definite singular article) means “the canonical injection that you get because $A$ is a subset of $B$”.

Comment: @S_Alex: Note that Lang doesn’t say “**an** injection”, he says **the** injection. The singular definite article means that you don’t have a choice of what map you pick: it must be **the** map that you have on hand by virtue of $A$ being a subset of $B$.

Comment: Now I understood! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Changed the notation from $S$ to $P$ (as it is in Lang). Well, maybe $\mathfrak P$, but it was too complicated.

Comment: @user26857: I was wondering, as I thought I had followed the original poster in so far as $B$ was concerned... but now I see you also edited the question itself. Thanks.